# Set Variable to Current Date with Power Automate Desktop

Tags: database, automation, power-automate, power-automate-desktop, power-automate-custom-connector

I want to set variable month to be able to get into folder with date number as the folder name (e.g. 24022024).

Now I can do it with set variable and set the value to the specific month like this. But, I wish to not having to change the value every month. Any idea of how I could achieve that?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you wish to get a formatted datetime value in MMyyyy format. You can basically just use the "Get current date and time" action and then convert that into text. Here is a screenshot of the setup of the action:

[image: Convert datetime to text setup]

Comment: yes! but i want to make it dynamic so it could retrieve current month without us having to change it to this month number

Comment: Well, the "Get current date and time" action gets exactly that - the current date and time. So if you run this for example in April you will get April, May-May etc.